What is the demonym for the United States in Latin?
I know very few things about Latin, but I do know that the name for the United States in (Neo-)Latin is "Civitates Foederatae Americae". Thus, I was wondering, is there any demonym in Latin for the US besides "Americanus"? Part of me feels wrong to say Americanus when it can also mean "from the whole Americas" (in fact, that is its main meaning in Latin as far as I know, unlike in English).
So, here's my two questions:

Is there any other demonym in Latin for the US besides Americanus? Are there records of any other word for this purpose? (Columbiensis, Usonianus, Foederatensis, Americensis, etc.)
I know this is unlikely to be a recorded form, but would it be technically correct to say "Civitatensis Foederati" (or something along those lines) as a demonym?


You might want to be more specific with "someone ever". I know it's not your intention, but it does invite bad options. You might also want to doubly specify new Latin, unless you're looking for historical developments (i.e. what do people say today v. Latin that was used when scholars were still writing monographs in Latin).

Do you know of any language with such a demonym for the inhabitants of the USA? (I can think of one based on "Yankees".) The word "American" has similar issues in all languages, including English, but convention trumps literal meaning. I don't see why we should treat Latin so differently from other languages.

@JoonasIlmavirta I do! In Spanish it is "estadounidense", in Portuguese it's "estadunidense", in Italian it's "statunitense" and in Catalan it's "estatunidenc". Also I find interesting that all these examples are from Romance languages and  consider "America" to mean "the Americas", so it kind of feels natural that New Latin would have an alternative too.

@user18632 That is very interesting! It reminds me of Esperanto, Usono and usonano (which you mentioned above). I don't have much experience with Spanish, but it is widely spoken here in the US, and I have heard the term Nord-americano (sp?) used to distinguish us from Mexicanos, who are also called Americanos. (I'm not sure how Canadians fit in.) That said, my English-Latin dictionary only lists Americanus for "American". It makes me wonder how you would translate "North American" into Latin. I'm not sure americanus septentrionalis quite covers it.

Interesting fact: the Catholic Church uses at least once Civitates Foederae Americae Septentrionalis

@JoonasIlmavirta in Latin American Spanish americano means mainly from the Americas, while American is estadounidense. Using americano for American used to be considered foreign/literal translation, but has gradually become more frequent

@Rafael Many people in Spanish also say "norteamericano" for US Americans (still not ideal because Canada and Mexico are also North American, but a bit better), so it makes sense they would use America Septentrionalis sometimes! Then maybe an acceptable demonym would be "Americanus Septentrionalis"?

@Joonas Ilmavirta Here are two examples from Germanic languages that incorporate the country name into the demonym: In German, the term US-Amerikaner for an American has been around since about 1900 and this usage appears to be ubiquitous now. In Dutch (possibly applicable to colloquial speech only), an American can be referred to as a VSer based on "VS" ="Verenigde Staten" = United States.
